# Display a class using :after

Tags: css, selector

I have a simple problem here. What I need to do is that I need to place a class after span in a button. Like if:

```
<button class="test-button"> 
<span>This is button</span>
</button>

<span class="custom"> I need to place this after Test button using :after </span>
```

So if its not clear, I need to place the custom class after the span of text-button class. I was trying to accomplish this by using

```
.test-button span:after {
    content:attr([class=".custom"]);
}
```

but its not working ...

Comment: You want to inject a `<span>` element *via* the `::after` pseudo-element? You can't do that. It may be better if you describe the end-result you'd like to achieve instead.

Comment: What I wan't to achieve is that I want to place the class `custom` in button so that the text is included in the button.

Comment: @FahadSohail: Even if you *could* inject HTML using CSS, your example is confusing because you're showing the `<span>` outside your `<button>`. Can you maybe rework that as a 'before' and 'after' - that might add some insight.

Comment: 1. The text isn't in a class, it's in a span which has a class (there could be many others with it too). 2. CSS controls the rendering of a document, it doesn't change the document. You could perhaps get what you want with javascript; with jQuery `$(".test-button").append(".custom")` move the "custom" span into the button, at the end of it, which seems to be along the lines you are talking about.

Comment: I understand, I guess I have to make the changes on back end. Well thanks for help ..

Comment: Well, if the jQuery above (or something similar) would do what you want, you could still keep all the changes client-side.

Answer (score 1):

`content:attr` doesn't work quite like that; it *fetches* the value of an attribute, rather than setting one ([see example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Examples)). I believe you can't set an attribute in that way - you'll have to apply the individual properties of `.custom` in the `:after` declaration manually.

Comment: What I wan't to achieve is that I want to place the class `custom` in button so that the text is included in the button. Any ideas?

Comment: As Jonathan Sampson points out, you can't actually modify the markup using CSS. You can create 'pseudo' elements, which have limited 'power' - is it possible for you to rephrase your question slightly to indicate what you're trying to do? You *could* have two `<span>` elements within that button, and toggle the display property on each one, as appropriate, to show one or the other - would that do what you want to achieve?